# How to update App.config using C#3.5 framework?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, c#-4.0

How to update in C#3.5 app.config file or Settings.settings file through C# code?

Please provide me the code related to C#3.5 framework support of classes but not with 2.0 framework classes in updating app.config file.

Comment: Why do you want to update app.config? It's not supposed to be updated, so it could help to know your reason to do it.

Comment: Check this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Change_AppConfig_File.aspx

Comment: @František: Why do say it's not supposed to be updated?  If it never changed, then it wouldn't need to exist, as it could just be compiled into the assembly, no?

Comment: @recursive: I mean updated programatically - sorry for misunderstanding (and it's still 'except for certain situations').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed with this issue on a project, and decided depending on circumstance to just use a simple XML config file of my own. The problem is app.config has application level and user level settings for a specific reason. The Code Project article mentioned by others here can get you there, but seems like a lot of work to me.

Easy way, create an XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths>
  <path name="pathtofile1">
    <fullpath>\\machine1\folder1\file.txt</fullpath>
  </path>
  <path name="pathtofile2">
    <fullpath>\\machine2\folder2\file2.txt</fullpath>
  </path>
</paths>
```

then use LINQ to get at a node:

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlfile);

var filePath1 = from c in doc.Descendants("path")
                where (string)c.Attribute("name") == "pathtofile1"
                select (string)c.Element("fullpath").Value;

string thePath = filePath1.First();
```

Of course you don't have the built in typing, but this is an easy, generic approach you can use in a lot of situations such as in dll classes.

Now that you are using a 'regular' xml file, you can use the techniques mentioned here to update it. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331502/linq-to-xml-update-alter-the-nodes-of-an-xml-document) and this [blog](http://blog.dimaj.net/2011/02/howto-update-xml-file-using-linq/) does a nice job.

Answer (score 0):

It's an XML file so you can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to open the file

```
var appConfigPath = string.Format("{0}{1}.exe.config", Directory.GetCurrent(), Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);

var appConfig = XDocument.Parse(appConfigPath);

//have at it
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: [Changing App.config at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008800/changing-app-config-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this code:

You have to load the web.congif first:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

Then you can modify or add it just like this:

```
if (config.AppSettings.Settings["YourTag"] == null)
{
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("YourTag", "yourValue");
}
else
{
    config.AppSettings.Settings["YourTag"].Value = "yourValue";
}
```

Comment: This code is related to 2.0 framework since Configuration is not in part of System.Configuration. Please provide me with .NET framework 3.5 related

Answer (score -1):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load("..\\App.config");

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/capabilities/single/add");// pass xpath of node
//node.Attributes[1].Value = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
node.Attributes[1].Value = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName;

xmlDoc.Save("..\\App.config");
```

Please write in main methods, it is working for me.