# Config file settings not refreshing until application restart

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

As the question title states, I'm saving some application settings (currently just a database path) to the application configuration file. The changes seem to save into the file ok, but when I then try to read the new data I get an empty string. The new data reads in fine if I restart the application, but I do need it to read in without having to restart the app. My config settings class is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HADDMS_Asset_Management_System
{
    public static class ConfigSettings
    {
        public static bool WriteSetting(string key, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(key);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error writing to configuration settings:\r\n" + e.ToString());
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public static string ReadSetting(string key)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        }

        public static string ReadSetting(int keyIndex)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
I should add that I am running the application from the release folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing App.config at Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008800/changing-app-config-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to refresh a section named `key`, which doesn't exist. You need to replace your call to `RefreshSection()` with this:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

You can test this out by doing this:

```
//keySection will be null
var keySection = config.GetSection(key);
```

The `ConfigurationManager` will apparently not throw an error when there is no section found matching the name provided to `RefreshSection()` which is interesting.

Comment: Exactly it, I misunderstood what a section was. Still a bit new to XML and config settings. Thanks a bunch and Happy Holidays!

Comment: Same to you, glad it was a simple fix