# Dynamically changing the value of AppSettings in App.config in a WCF WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm trying to change the value of a key in the `<appSettings>` section of the `app.config` file at runtime so that it represents a proper date, but for some reason when running the program it doesn't change anything at all. I've tried the code and it worked in other occasions with test projects, but for some reason it doesn't work here.

Here's the code in question:

```
private void ChangeSyncDate(DateTime date)
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); // Open App.config
    config.AppSettings.Settings["SyncDate"].Value = date.ToString();
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

And this is the function that uses that code:

```
public List<Business.Reservation> RequestReservationRetrieval()
{
        string syncstring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SyncDate"];
        List<Business.Reservation> webReservations;

        using (repo = new ReservationRepository())
        {
            webReservations = repo.ObtainReservations();
        }

        if(syncstring.Equals("nil"))
        {
            ChangeSyncDate(DateTime.Now); // and here
            return webReservations;
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime syncdate = Convert.ToDateTime(syncstring);

            foreach(Reservation r in webReservations)
            {
                if (r.Date <= DateTime.Now && r.Date >= syncdate)
                    webReservations.Remove(r);
            }

            ChangeSyncDate(DateTime.Now); // here
            return webReservations;
        }
    }
```

As it stands, the value in `app.config` that I mean to change isn't changing at all.

This is the value I'm trying to modify:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SyncDate" value="nil"/>
</appSettings>
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Is it app.config or web.config file?

Comment: Shows up as App.config in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing App.config at Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008800/changing-app-config-at-runtime)

Comment: you can also do this using `XPATH` I would suggest doing a `stackoverflow google search` there are plenty examples on how to do this

Comment: I did do a somewhat big google search on this, I even tried it repeatedly on several other projects to make sure it worked, when I implemented it in the webservice it didn't work which is why I ended up posting here.

Comment: If its WCF Service as question title says then it has to be web.config. If its Windows executable then it has  to be app.config. Your code is for modifying contents of config file of executable and not for configuration of web application. Let us know if its exe or wcf service?

Comment: perhaps you are trying to update the wrong .config file..

Comment: That could be possible, yet still there are only two .config files in the webservice's solution: App.config and packages.config. Considering that there's a package.config on the other projects I tested it on I am assuming that it should have worked. These are the files in the WebService's project: http://puu.sh/frftV/a0d4b6b7ed.png

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but the app.settings is not the right place to do this. App settings are really for settings which are set at install time. In most situations you won't have write access to the file. Instead I'd recommend you store this information elsewhere. For example make an object which represents your "transient data" including a property for SyncDate - serialize this using something like xml or json and store that on disk.

Comment: You are probably right, I will do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using WebConfigurationManager not ConfigurationManager to open the AppSettings. Give it a try.

Comment: For some reason there's no System.Web.Configuration reference and therefore I can't use WebConfigurationManager!